# why typescript's structure typing is inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, typescript

we know that typescript applies structure typing as below example shows:

```js
interface Vector {
   x: number;
   y: number;
}

interface NamedVector {
   x: number;
   y: number;
   name: string;
}

function calculateLength(v: Vector) {
   return Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
}

const v: NamedVector = { x: 3, y: 4, name: 'zee' };
calculateLength(v);   // compile OK, result is 5
```

It allowed `calculateLength` to be called with a `NamedVector` because its structure was compatible with `Vector`.

But in term of assignment, it doesn't use structure typing anymore:

```
const v: Vector = { x: 3, y: 4, name: 'Zee' };  // compile error, 'name' does not exist in type 'Vector'
```

according to the definition of structure typing, `{ x: 3, y: 4, name: 'Zee' }` is also compatible with `Vector`, so why structure typing doesn't work here?

and what is the Utility Types I can use to describe a type that must contains `x` and `y` fields and also some other fields so I can do:

```
const v: XXX<Vector> = { x: 3, y: 4, name: 'Zee' };
```

Comment: Why are you trying to type `v`, a `NamedVector` as a `Vector`? This example doesn't make much sense

Comment: Well, you can do this: `const test: NamedVector = { x: 3, y: 4, name: 'Zee' }; const v: Vector = test;`.

Comment: Anyway, if that `const v: Vector = ... name: 'Zee' }` were allowed, the code after it will not know that your `v` has a `name` property, so the `name` here seems to be unusable info. I guess the restriction ("Object literal may only specify known properties") was added to prevent typo-related problems. Anyway, if you want to literally allow any extra key, you can try `interface Vector { x: number; y: number; [key: string]: any }`

Comment: Read more about [Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks): there is an example where someone mistyped `color` as `colour` and typescript detects it.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of a single use-case where this would be make sense but the simplest way to down-cast is to, well, cast

```ts
const v = { x: 3, y: 4, name: 'Zee' } as Vector;
```

Of course you won't be able to access `v.name` so again, this seems a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question

```
interface Vector {
   x: number;
   y: number;
}
const v: Vector & {[x:string]: any}= { x: 3, y: 4, name: 'Zee' };
```

[TypescriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQWA9lZBvAKGWIA8AuZEAVwFsAjaAbiOIE8Lr6mCBfAhLCADOYZADcK6TDmQAyfAG1yIqKADmAXQpwQrHgF58ycsgDMAGmTtkAFksg4NCBQDkALQgQXyHo2QEgA)

The first question is not specific enough to answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use excess property when use Object literal. So you should use Custom Genernics not to use excess property.

```
interface Vector {
   x: number;
   y: number;
}

interface NamedVector {
   x: number;
   y: number;
   name: string;
}

function calculateLength(v: Vector) {
   return Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
}

type Optional<T, N extends keyof T> = Partial<Pick<T, N>> & Omit<T, N>;

const v: Optional<NamedVector, "name"> = { x: 3, y: 4, name: 'Zee' };
calculateLength(v);
```

> ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out